# Oracle: Change range parition to Hash partition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a range partitioned table in oracle, it is possible to change that table to hash partition without dropping partition and recreating? Please suggest commands or good link for this one.

Also I like to know if we can use range partition table to create another table in database but using another partition option. below is the example I am referring to:

```
create table t2 
hash partition clause
as select * from t1;
```

Here t1 is a range partitioned table and t2 will be new table with hash partition. is this work in oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new table is the only real option here. You can do online redefinition, or expdp/imdp, but ultimately it comes down to

- creating a new table and
- moving the data and
- getting the right privileges on it and
- adding indexes.

The rest is just ways of avoiding issues like application downtime or lack of space in the database.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and quick repsonse. Do you think query mentioned in my question will work or should I undo partition first and redo with hash?

Comment: I don't understand "should I undo partition first and redo with hash"

Comment: I have one table which is range partitioned now. I like to try hash partition on the same table. I am looking for the quick and easy way to change the partition range partition to hash. I do not have any backup etc for this table. It is big table 3 billion rows and I am looking for a way which will take smallest time.

Comment: I would use a nologging direct path insert with any required indexes already defined on the table. Apply parallel query if possible